# Angular Mat table highlight a column

Tags: angular, mat-table

Is it possible to highlight a column in mat-table ? I can see some examples for highlighting rows but i cannot find anything about highlighting columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css to do that. Following css highlights the 1st column to red and 3rd column to green.

```
.mat-header-cell:first-child,
.mat-cell:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(3),
.mat-cell:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```